# Melting a sparse matrix (dgCMatrix) and keeping its zeros

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, melt

I have a large `sparse matrix` (a `Matrix` package `dgCMatrix` object in `R`).

Toy example:

```
m <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5)
rownames(m) <- paste0("g",1:3)
colnames(m) <- paste0("c",1:3)
> m
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
g1  .  1  .  .  2
g2  .  .  2  .  1
g3  2  .  1  .  .
```

And I want to `melt` it to a `data.frame`.

`reshape2`'s `melt` requires coercing this `dgCMatrix` to a `matrix` object and for the dimensions I'm working with this is very slow. So I'm looking for something more efficient.

I thought `mefa4`'s `Melt` would do the trick but it's dropping the zero values:

```
> mefa4::Melt(m)
  rows cols value
1   g3   c1     2
2   g1   c2     1
3   g2   c3     2
4   g3   c3     1
5   g1   c5     2
6   g2   c5     1
```

And I would like to keep them and I don't see a parameter in `mefa4::Melt`'s manual providing that. Any ideas on an alternative?

Comment: The whole point of a sparse matrix is that it doesn’t have any zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

data:

```
m <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5)
rownames(m) <- paste0("g",1:3)
colnames(m) <- paste0("c",1:5)
```

Solution:

```
data.frame(rows=rownames(x)[row(x)],cols=colnames(x)[col(x)],value=as.numeric(x))
```

This seems to be faster than `reshape2`'s `melt` of the coerced `matrix` and `mefa4`'s `Melt`:

```
mf <- function(x){
  mefa4::Melt(x)
}

df <- function(x){
  data.frame(rows=rownames(x)[row(x)],cols=colnames(x)[col(x)],value=as.numeric(x))
}

rs <- function(x){
  reshape2::melt(Matrix::as.matrix(x))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(df(m))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 df(m) 330.378 376.887 778.3489 476.903 699.743 14953.47   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rs(m))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
 rs(m) 537.328 638.683 1197.268 726.679 1042.261 15073.3   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mf(m))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mf(m) 459.947 526.6585 1023.575 677.9775 1007.214 6712.497   100
```